# Js don`t send post query

Tags: javascript, html, forms, web

I have a form on the website that was supposedly working before the design changes. A captcha is attached to the form, but for some reason, after pressing the button, the JS script that sends the form data to the server does not work, I cannot understand why it does not work.
I'm new to this business and I don't have anyone to ask my friends about this problem, I will be very grateful for help!

HTML:

```
<form id="contact-form">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

              <div class="form-group"><label for="fio">Імʼя</label>

                <div class="input-group" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip"
                  title="Не варто використовувати спецсимволи, лише літери">
                  <input class="form-control" id="fio" placeholder="Ваше ім'я та прізвище" required="required"
                    type="text" />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group"><label for="phone">Телефон</label>
                <div class="input-group" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Наприклад: +380971111111">
                  <input class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="+380xxxxxxxxx" required="required" type="text" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1"><button class="btn btn-skin" data-badge="inline" id="btnRequest"
                type="submit">Відправити
                заявку</button></div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

JS:

```
 $("#btnRequest").on("click", function (e) {
  console.log("12");
  e.preventDefault(); //Здесь внимательно!!!!!!!!!!!! Форма не пашет по дефолту!!!
  let form = $(this); // запишем форму, чтобы потом не было проблем с this
  let error = false;

  if (validText($("#fio")) && validPhone($("#phone"))) {
    console.log("Here must be ajax request");
    var fio = $("#fio").val(),
      phone = $("#phone").val();
    if (!error) {
      form.find("input, textarea").each(function () {
        // пробежим по каждому полю в форме
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
          // если находим пустое
          alert('Заполните поле "' + $(this).attr("placeholder") + '"!'); // говорим заполняй!
          error = true; // ошибка
        }
      });
      var data = form.serialize();
      //console.log(street+'  '+building+'  '+room+'  '+fio+'  '+phone+'  '+tarif);
      $.ajax({
        // инициализируем ajax запрос
        type: "POST", // отправляем в POST формате, можно GET
        url: "send.php", // путь до обработчика, у нас он лежит в той же папке
        dataType: "json", // ответ ждем в json формате
        data: {
          usr_fio: fio,
          usr_phone: phone,
        }, // данные для отправки
        beforeSend: function (data) {
          // событие до отправки
          form.find("#btnRequest").attr("disabled", "disabled"); // например, отключим кнопку, чтобы не жали по 100 раз
        },
        success: function (data) {
          // событие после удачного обращения к серверу и получения ответа
          if (data["error"]) {
            // если обработчик вернул ошибку
            alert(data["error"]); // покажем её текст
          } else {
            // если все прошло ок
            alert("Лист відправлено! З Вами зв'яжуться!"); // пишем что все ок
          }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          // в случае неудачного завершения запроса к серверу
          alert(xhr.status); // покажем ответ сервера
          alert(thrownError); // и текст ошибки
        },
        complete: function (data) {
          // событие после любого исхода
          form.find("#btnRequest").prop("disabled", false); // в любом случае включим кнопку обратно
        },
      });
    } else {
      console.log("Something went wrong..");
    }
  }
});
```

I tried to change the names of the placeholders, the id of the button, but the script simply does not go.

UPDATE:
So far, I have updated the latest options, with which everything should work, but the js code is not called, added a complete form and removed the captcha

Comment: You need to debug the code. Are there any errors in the console? Check if event handler gets called by adding console.log in the function and trace down where it stops.

Comment: I tried to trace the code, but it doesn't get called, console.log() doesn't appear in the console

Comment: Are you talking about this console log `console.log("Here must be ajax request");` If this is not called then try moving the log up outside if condition

Comment: I mean that even before calling the function, if you put console.log('1'), then 1 will not be in the console anyway. No errors that the file is missing or any other errors are not visible in the console.

Comment: So that sounds like the js file is not correctly loaded in the page

Comment: The file loads correctly, as other functions work without problems, such as the preloader, or checking for empty fields in the form.

Comment: Did you put the JS code before the HTML in the web page? If so then it will try to assign the click event handler to the element, but the element does not exist yet, therefore it will not bind, and the event handler will never execute. That could easily be the cause of your problem. In that case, either swap the order you load the items into the page, or wrap the handler code in a `$(document).ready(function() { .. });` block so it waits to assign the handler until the whole page has loaded.

Comment: If that is not the issue, then you need to update the question to provide a full [mre] of the issue, because it's not obvious, from what's shown, what else could be  happening.

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given code? Did you check whether the request is sent as expected? If this is the case, PHP is not related. If the request is sent properly, but not handled properly, share more details about the PHP code

Comment: Thanks for the update. Here's a demo of HTML and the event part: https://jsfiddle.net/7fhpmy35/ . It shows that, if defined correctly, in the right part of your page, the "click" event will definitely happen and log to the console. Check what I said above about the positioning of the code in the page (you haven't told us anything about that in your update), and also that you don't have anything silly like two buttons with the same id or something.

Comment: This script is located on the server in the file js/script.js, there are also other scripts that open and close the modal form, start the preloader. All functions work, but for some reason the specific one that I provided is not called.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76572080/js-dont-send-post-query#comment135008023_76572080 again

Comment: I have like 3 buttons with id "btnRequest", аnd because of this it may not work?

Comment: Well yes, it might. It's probably binding the "click" event to one of the other buttons. IDs must be **unique** in a HTML document. In fact they must be unique in any part of life - that is the whole meaning of an ID! Therefore, when you write `$("#btnRequest")` jQuery will assume there is only one such button, will bind the event to the first one it finds, and completely ignore the others with the same ID, because they are not supposed to be there. Here's a demo of that: https://jsfiddle.net/7fhpmy35/1/ - it will only run the click from "button 1", not from the other one.

Comment: If you want to bind the same event to multiple similar buttons, you must use something like a class selector instead, because the same class can legitimately exist on multiple HTML elements. Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/7fhpmy35/3/ ...this time it will run the click on both buttons

Comment: Well, we have an answer.
Indeed, because of the same id, nothing worked, thanks!

Comment: No problem. Please ensure you understand some of the basics of HTML such as this :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the solution was to make unique ids for fields in the form

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).